# Show status for @{push} as well as @{upstream} in `git status`

Tags: git

For Pull Requests, I have:

- a local branch, e.g. `my-pr-branch`
- the [`@{upstream}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtupstreamemegemmasterupstreamememuem) branch tracking the branch the PR will be merged into (e.g. `up/master`)
- the [`@{push}`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltbranchnamegtpushemegemmasterpushemempushem) branch tracking the fork remote branch (e.g. `fork/my-pr-branch`)

`git status` nicely shows the `@{upstream}` delta with e.g.: `Your branch is up to date with 'up/master'.`

But what I really want is to see both `@{upstream}` and `@{push}` information.

I can add it manually, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, `git status` is all hard-coded. You could perhaps write something fancy and try to get it adopted upstream. It would be nice if there were a Git program with `--format` arguments that could produce status information (clean/dirty index, clean/dirty work-tree, ahead/behind counts for @{u} and @{push}, etc.) and that might be a plumbing variant of `git status`. Note that such a program might be ideal for the bash prompt stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following `status` alias (I run `git s` instead of `git status` already) in my `~/.config/git/config`:

```sh
[alias]
  s   = "!git status && git push-status #" # Status including delta from @{push}.

  # Show the status of this branch relative to @{push}.
  push-status = "! push_branch=$(git push-branch 2>/dev/null) || { echo \"No push branch set.\" && exit 0; } \
    ; both=$(git rev-list --left-right --count HEAD...@{push}) \
    ; [[ $both == '0    0' ]] && echo \"Your branch is up to date with push branch $push_branch.\" \
    || echo \"Your branch is ${both%%   *} commit(s) ahead and ${both##*    } commit(s) behind push branch $push_branch.\" #"
```

This will give output that looks something like:

```
On branch my-pr-branch
Your branch and 'up/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Your branch is 2 commit(s) ahead and 1 commit(s) behind push branch fork/my-pr-branch.
```

It's not as good as having something built-in, but it works.

---

#### Including in a prompt

To make it show up in your prompt, you might already be getting the delta from the upstream, you can simply augment that with:

```sh
# Previous command to check upstream delta:
upstream_delta=$(command git rev-list --left-right --count 'HEAD...@{u}')
# New command to check push delta:
push_upstream_delta=$(command git rev-list --left-right --count 'HEAD...@{push}')
```

Output looks like: `0   0` (two numbers separated by a tab). First number is commits ahead, second is commits behind.

If you were using ⇣⇡ for upstream delta, you might like ⇠⇢ for push delta.

Comment: Suggestion: write your rev counting code as a shell function, and use `set -- $(git rev-list --left-right --count <args>)`. Then you have `$1` and `$2` as the two counts, which is more convenient to work with than string replacements.

Comment: Nice idea! I'm currently using a fork of the [pure prompt](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/blob/master/pure.zsh#L331) so I modified it [like this](https://github.com/gibfahn/dot/commit/5cecd6e4149ddac20caa143c2b8253aa67ce1970#diff-18c38158d5ad123d605f27b3386c13efR265) to get it to work, but if I'd been writing from scratch that looks nicer.